# Find missing rows in Powershell 2D arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have 2 arrays, and each array has 2 fields ('item' and 'price' for example).

The following is the get-member result on 1 of my arrays (actually both arrays have the same structure)

```
   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition                    
----        ----------   ----------                    
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()             
GetType     Method       type GetType()                
ToString    Method       string ToString()             
item        NoteProperty System.String field1=computer 
price       NoteProperty System.String field2=2000
```

I need to find the items in array $shopA where the items is not found in array $shopB.  I am now using 2 loops to find the missing item.

```
$missing = @()
foreach ($itemA in $shopA) {
  $found = 0
  foreach ($itemB in $shopB) {
    if ($itemB.item -eq $itemA.item) {
      $found = 1
    }
  }
  if ($found = 0) {
    $missing += $itemA
  }
}
```

This method works for me but my 2 arrays are quite large and I want a quicker method than looping thru the whole array...

I have been finding a better way to do this and the compare-object almost does the job but all the examples seem to work for single dimension array only.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see you do have two 1D arrays, despite you claiming the opposite.

A naïve way of finding the missing items would be

```
$missing = $shopA | ? { $x = $_; !($shopB | ? {$_.item -eq $x.item})}
```

However, this will always be O(n²); to make it quicker you can collect all items from `$shopB` in a hastable first, which makes checking for existence O(1), not O(n):

```
$hash = @{}
$shopB | %{ $hash[$_.item] = 1 }
$missing = $shopA | ?{ !$hash.ContainsKey($_.item) }
```

Comment: Thanks Joey.  I was wondering if I can solve the problem without building another hash table, but if that's the best way, I will create a hash table then.

Comment: You mention large arrays, so from a performance standpoint you should create the hashtable for checking existence.

Comment: I will also try to use compare-object if I need to create a new table.  Thanks a lot and your suggest is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
 $shopA= @(1, 2, 3, 4)
 $shopB= @(4, 3, 5, 6)
 $shopB | where { $shopA -notcontains $_  }
```

Comment: Thanks David.  What if the arrays are 2 dimensional?  I've tried your suggestion with my data but it didn't work.

Comment: Note that their items have properties and thus normal equality will probably not work directly.